# Create aws dynamodb table by yml file

Tags: yaml, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I am trying to create a dynamodb table from yml file to make a microservice, but it tells me that the table does not exist

Error:
UPDATE_FAILED: productGroupTable (AWS::DynamoDB::Table)
Resource handler returned message: "Table: productGroupTableDev does not exist." (RequestToken: bdc2ae26-5fde-6965-8609-bdaddff79ddf, HandlerErrorCode: NotFound)

this is my yml file

```
custom:
  product: wms
  modelName: productGroups
  microServiceAction: create
  microServiceVersion: v1
  microService: wms-productGroups-create-v1
  capacities:
    - table: productGroupTable
      read:
        minimum: 5       # Minimum read capacity
        maximum: 100     # Maximum read capacity
        usage: 0.60      # Targeted usage percentage
      write:
        minimum: 5       # Minimum write capacity
        maximum: 50      # Maximum write capacity
        usage: 0.60      # Targeted usage percentage

resources:
  Resources:
    productGroupTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        TableName: productGroupTableDev
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: external_id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 5
          WriteCapacityUnits: 5
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: "external_id-index"
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: external_id
                KeyType: HASH
            Projection:
              NonKeyAttributes:
              ProjectionType: KEYS_ONLY
            ProvisionedThroughput:
              ReadCapacityUnits: 5
              WriteCapacityUnits: 5


provider:
  environment:
      MICROSERVICE_CREATE_PRODUCT_GROUP: wms-productGroups-create-v1-lambda-dev
      
plugins:
  - serverless-dynamodb-autoscaling

functions:
  P_1_3_1_productGroup_create:
    name: wms-productGroups-create-v1-lambda-dev
    handler: src.P_1_3_1_productGroup_create.core.handler.product_groups_create
    environment:
      DB_NAME: productGroupTableDev
      JSON_SCHEMA_PATH: ./src/P_1_3_1_productGroup_create/core/wms-productGroups-create-v1-schema.json 
    timeout: 30
    events: 
      - http: 
          method: POST
          path: products/create/groups/
          cors: true
        # request: 
            # schemas:
              # application/json: ${self:provider.apiGateway.request.schemas.model}
              # if you want to raise schema validator error from api gateway
              # application/json: ${self:provider.apiGateway.request.schemas.model.schema}
      - eventBridge:
          pattern:
            source:
              - wms-serverless.dev.event
            detail-type:
              - CREATE_PRODUCT_GROUP
```

my iam policities

```
Policies:
          - PolicyName: ${self:custom.microService}-${opt:stage, 'dev'}-lambda
            PolicyDocument:
              Version: '2012-10-17'
              Statement: [
                {
                  Effect: 'Allow',
                  Action: [
                    'cognito-idp:AdminInitiateAuth',
                    'events:PutEvents',
                    'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                  ],
                  Resource: '*'
                },
                {
                  Effect: 'Allow',
                  Action: [
                    'dynamodb:GetItem',
                    'dynamodb:Scan',
                    'dynamodb:PutItem'
                  ], 
                  Resource: 'arn:aws:dynamodb:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:table/*'
                },
                {
                  Effect: 'Allow',
                  Action: [
                    'logs:CreateLogGroup',
                    'logs:CreateLogStream',
                    'logs:PutLogEvents'
                  ],
                  Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:${aws:region}:${aws:accountId}:log-group:/aws/lambda/*'
                }
              ]
```

Answer (score 0):

nice to meet you!

Try to create the table into AWS in the Web Browser first, and try it again.

Comment: Hello, if I create it manually if it allows me, but I need to create it in the deployment...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using CloudFormation. With it, you have the `stack deploy option`, which will create the stack if it doesn't exist or update it if needed.

> Deploys the specified AWS CloudFormation template by creating and then
> executing a change set. The command terminates after AWS
> CloudFormation executes the change set. If you want to view the change
> set before AWS CloudFormation executes it, use the
> --no-execute-changeset flag.
>
> To update a stack, specify the name of an existing stack. To create a
> new stack, specify a new stack name.

From this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/deploy/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the resource

```
Resources:
 productGroupTableTest:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  TableName: "productGroupTableDev"
......
```

do the deploy

and then if the logical name its important to you

```
Resources:
 productGroupTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  TableName: "productGroupTableDev"
......
```

My theory is that for some reason cloudformation recognizes that logical name as something that already exists, so it tries to update it, and to update it it needs to exist, so in this way when changing the resource name it removes the logical name from the stack, and in the second instance that name is already available to be a "creation"